# Python string split results in characters alternating with null bytes

Tags: python, string

I am trying to parse a text file. I want to split lines into tokens, but use of the split command results in "\x00" strings alternating with every character I see.

**example 1:** A line such as

```
"Language" "English"
```

becomes

```
['\x00"\x00L\x00a\x00n\x00g\x00u\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00"\x00', '\x00"\x00E\x00n\x00g\x00l\x00i\x00s\x00h\x00"\x00\r\x00']
```

after `line.split("//")[0].strip().split(None, 1)`

**example 2**: A simple line consisting of

```
{
```

becomes

```
['\x00{\x00', '\x00']
```

I wonder if it's something to do with the encoding of the text file, which I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: Your text file is encoded using UTF-16. Open it accordingly

Comment: well default decoding format used is UTF-8 hence either you should store your file in UTF-8 format or you need to specify decode format such as `data.read().decode('utf-16-le')` refer this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) too

Comment: thanks for the information